# Difference between Dependencies, References, Imports, namespace & assemblies?

Tags: compilation

Can someone make a definitive (for newbies) explanation of those terms and the way they are interlinked? (Dependencies, References, Imports, namespace & assemblies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dependency is a resource your assembly requires before it itself can be compiled and built eg a dll or exe

A reference is a link to that dependency

An import is what you use to avail of the objects and items within that reference

Objects and items within that reference are collected in logical buckets known as namespaces. It is namespaces that you import.

Assemblies are the constructed output of the compiler and builder. They can in turn be an executable or a service or indeed a dependency that another component is dependent on